# How to build graph Google Chart from PHP data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, charts, laravel-5

I use Laravel and Google Chart.

The script of chart is located in `file.js`, that is connected to page via `<script>`:

Now array of data look as:

```
var rawData = [
        [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '03/02/13'}, 1]];
```

So, How I can transfer array data from PHP in this JS script in Laravel?

Comment: There's actually a really good library for this: https://github.com/kevinkhill/lavacharts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have a couple options. You can either fetch the data through a get request (API) or you can transform the data from PHP into a javascript object using for an example Laracasts' PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer package. 
Please see https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer.

For prototyping you can also inline the javascript into your blade files and then have access to the php-variables like always.

Hope that gets the job done for you :D